# Merge two folders with conflict resolution strategy

Tags: files, rsync, unison

When I merge two folders with `rsync`, if files of the same name exist in the "target" directory, those will be kept unconditionally. I can use `unison` which is a bit more advanced, but as far as I know it only looks at file creation time and picks the newer one.

In my case, files under the same path with the same name are indeed semantically the same, but they might have different sizes.

I want to merge based on file size and not creation time. Is there a utility that supports this case or do I have to write a script for that?

Unfortunately, I can't give an estimate of how many differently-sized files will be encountered. Might be anywhere between a small double-digit number to somewhere in the 10'000s.

Comment: I would definitely go for the script.  `rsync` as far as I know is not able to make that differentiation.  The `--itemize-changes` option together with `-ia` can give a list of files to be modified/updated. Using option `-n` will run in test mode and only list you the files, indicating which ones need to be changed. This list can be used as a source for your script.